# Is it possible to do read-only copiable (by reference) shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, reference, constants, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I'm trying to create a Read Only shared_ptr, shared between multiple instances. None of the instances should be able to modify the content of the pointer's object. But the instances should be able to copy it for an unknown period.

a `const std::shared_ptr<T>` cannot easily get stored in a attribute reference, as it has to be defined by the constructor. (and a const reference is, by definition, constant)

i did a wrapper class

```
template<class T>
class const_shared_ptr
{
    public:

    const_shared_ptr(std::shared_ptr<T> ptr) 
    {
      m_ptr = ptr;
    }



    const T* get() const
    {
        return m_ptr.get();
    }

    private:

    std::shared_ptr<T> m_ptr;


}
```

is this code clean ? or is there a more simpler way of doing ? this looks like a pretty easy problem but i can't figure any solution.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<const T>`?

Comment: @Quentin the object can be edited by other classes. or maybe should I go from a non const shared to a const shared at some point ?

Comment: No it can't. Dereferencing a `std::shared_ptr<const T>` will yield a `const T &`, which is read-only. This mirrors what raw pointers do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can initialize a shared pointer to a const object from a shared pointer to a non-const object.

```
#include <memory>


void foo ()
{
    auto v = std::make_shared <int> (10);

    std::shared_ptr <int const> x = v;

    // *x = 10; ERROR
}
```

Comment: easy and quick answer, thank you a lot! i really was doing an over complicated thing